# re.sub with unicode in Python 2.7

Tags: regex, python-2.7, unicode

I would like to add some spaces before and after some Tibetan characters in a text file and have used the re.sub() successfully for multiple lines of replacements of all normal characters in that same file. If I do the same for one line of re.sub replacements for the Tibetan characters, it works too, no matter which character (so all unicode sequences are correct). However, if I try multiple lines of re.sub() for Tibetan characters, it finds all correct strings, but replaces it with the wrong string of characters (the ones of the first line). This is the relevant part of my code (I use Python 2.7):

```
import codecs, re, os

text = codecs.open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8') 

def cs(text):

    for line in text:
        #line = re.sub('<utt>','',line)
        #line = re.sub('//','/',line)
        line = re.sub(ur'[\u0f62\u0f0b]/ES', ur' \u0f62\u0f0b ',line)
        line = re.sub(ur'[\u0f60\u0f72\u0f0b]/ES', ur' \u0f60\u0f72\u0f0b ',line)
        print line
```

Both lines with unicode work separately and give the right replacement (although the character is doubled in the output, instead of replaced). Combined, they find the different characters, but always replace it with the first ur' \u0f62\u0f0b ', instead of what it should be. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

This is a sample of the output I get (just focusing on the Tibetan lines):

པར ར་ སཱིའི ར་ འདུལ་//X བ་/E ག་/S བཞུགས་/S སོ/S །/S

This is the first line from the input test file:

པར་/ES སཱིའི་/ES འདུལ་//X བ་/E ག་/S བཞུགས་/S སོ/S །/S

It goes right with the first word, but wrong with the second, representing the first and second line of the unicode re.sub respectively. The desired output is the following with space around the last characters of the first two words because they have an /ES tag:

པ ར་ སཱི འི་ འདུལ་//X བ་/E ག་/S བཞུགས་/S སོ/S །/S

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without some example input and expected output.  My guess is that those square brackets aren't doing quite what you want, but I have no way of knowing what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I've added input and output now. Yes, I thought it was the square brackets, but I've tried all possible alternative positions for them, but that didn't help.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: The only thing in that text that matches either regex is ``\u0f0b/ES``, and that matches both of them, so I still have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.  Is turning ``པར་/ES`` into ``པར ར་`` (with duplication of the \u0F62 character) actually what you want the first regex to do?

Comment: I suspect you want to remove the brackets.  `'[\u0f62\u0f0b]/ES'` is going to match *either* `\u0f62/ES` or `\u0f0b/ES`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your attempts, I've added the desired output, hoping that it helps. I just need spaces around the last characters of words that are tagged with /ES. And then the /ES can be removed, so effectively, I'm replacing some unicode string of Tibetan characters + /ES with a space + that same character + a space. So the duplication of the character is wrong indeed. Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

`'[\u0f62\u0f0b]/ES'` is going to match either `\u0f62/ES` or `\u0f0b/ES`, which isn't what you want.  Just remove the brackets.

Also, your sample original text had a space after each /ES, so the replacement doesn't need to add another one.

Finally, these seem to be simple replacements, so no need for the `re` module.

```
original = u'\u0f54\u0f62\u0f0b/ES \u0f66\u0f71\u0f72\u0f60\u0f72\u0f0b/ES \u0f60\u0f51\u0f74\u0f63\u0f0b//X \u0f56\u0f0b/E \u0f42\u0f0b/S \u0f56\u0f5e\u0f74\u0f42\u0f66\u0f0b/S \u0f66\u0f7c/S \u0f0d/S'
desired = u'\u0f54 \u0f62\u0f0b \u0f66\u0f71\u0f72 \u0f60\u0f72\u0f0b \u0f60\u0f51\u0f74\u0f63\u0f0b//X \u0f56\u0f0b/E \u0f42\u0f0b/S \u0f56\u0f5e\u0f74\u0f42\u0f66\u0f0b/S \u0f66\u0f7c/S \u0f0d/S'

print 'org =',original
print 'desired =',desired

attempt = original.replace(u'\u0f62\u0f0b/ES', u' \u0f62\u0f0b').replace(u'\u0f60\u0f72\u0f0b/ES', u' \u0f60\u0f72\u0f0b')
print 'attempt =',attempt
print attempt == desired
```

Output:

```
org = པར་/ES སཱིའི་/ES འདུལ་//X བ་/E ག་/S བཞུགས་/S སོ/S །/S
desired = པ ར་ སཱི འི་ འདུལ་//X བ་/E ག་/S བཞུགས་/S སོ/S །/S
attempt = པ ར་ སཱི འི་ འདུལ་//X བ་/E ག་/S བཞུགས་/S སོ/S །/S
True
```

If you still want to use the `re` module, the following will do the two replacements in one pass over the line.  It matches one of the two sequences, replacing the match with space+match and removes the /ES.

```
attempt = re.sub(ur'(\u0f62\u0f0b|\u0f60\u0f72\u0f0b)/ES',ur' \1',original)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I use regexs in most other replacements I have to do, so that's why I just tried to use the same method for this. Both seem to work now, though if I print the lines in python ran from the terminal it looks like the result is wrong for the second one. If I copy and paste to some text editor I see it's perfectly fine. I tried to write the result to a file directly with the below code, but that doesn't seem to work though, it just gives me an empty file: `output_file = codecs.open('outputtest.txt', 'w','utf-8')
        output_file.write(line)
        output_file.close()`

Comment: (`line` is my result of all replacements, which worked writing it to a normal file without utf-8 encoding. Now I have ` line = re.sub(ur'(\u0f62\u0f0b|\u0f60\u0f72\u0f0b)/ES', ur' \1',line)` with the codecs utf-8 way of write to file but it doesn't work.

Comment: The code looks fine. Do you print line before you write it to the file? If you're getting a blank file, line would have to be empty.

Comment: Yes, I tested with `print line` and without `print line` but both give me an empty output file, so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Since this is now a different problem, I suggest posting a new question with a small repeatable example of the problem.